# Eclipse: don't include some maven dependencies at runtime

Tags: eclipse, gwt, maven, classpath, lombok

I am running a GWT + GAE Maven project in Eclipse, which has a dependency on the lombok jar:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
        <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
        <version>0.9.3</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
```

I then launch my application using the Google Plugin for Eclipse.
It all works fine, except that the lombok jar is present in the classpath at runtime (System.getProperty("java.class.path") shows the jar is included). And this is supposed to [a cause some issues with app engine / datanucleus](http://code.google.com/p/projectlombok/issues/detail?id=112#c3).

I checked:
- The jar is not copied in the war/WEB-INF/lib folder
- The jar is present in the Maven Dependencies of the project build path
- The Maven Dependencies are automatically included in the Classpath of the project configuration.

What I am looking for is a means to avoid having the jar being part of the runtime classpath.

Thanks in advance for any hint you may offer,

Sébastien

Comment: Using the latest version of lombok (0.10.0-RC1) solves the issue. Waiting for the imparted time to answer my own question.

Comment: Nice to hear you solved it! ;-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using the latest version of lombok (0.10.0-RC1) solves the issue.

Answer (score 0):

You need to define the `scope` as `provided`. This assumes you will have the dependency provided for your application at runtime. It will, of course, be used to compile your code.

Comment: Sorry, corrected the original post too late. The dependency I use has a "provided" scope; And indeed, the jar is not copied in the WBE-INF/lib folder.
However, Maven still seems to see it as a dependency, and it is included at runtime

Comment: Ah...
Okay... Well, then maybe the GWT app runner is adding it to the classpath...?

Comment: The configuration I use to launch the application is:  
Program Arguments:  
`-remoteUI "${gwt_remote_ui_server_port}:${unique_id}" -startupUrl TheFiveOrbs.jsp -logLevel INFO -server com.google.appengine.tools.development.gwt.AppEngineLauncher -port 8888 -codeServerPort 9997 -war "D:\Dev\Projects\The Five Orbs\trunk\target\fiveorbs-0.1" com.fiveorbs.TheFiveOrbs`

VM arguments  
`-javaagent:D:\Dev\Programs\apengine-java-sdk\lib\agent\appengine-agent.jar -Xmx512m -Dappengine.sdk.root=D:\Dev\Programs\appengine-java-sdk`

Answer (score 0):

Looks a lot like http://code.google.com/p/google-web-toolkit/issues/detail?id=4929